# Pitfall uncountable union of $\sigma$-algebras

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \mathbb{R}_+$ and let $\mathcal{F}_t = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+)$ for each $ t \in \mathbb{R}_+$. Then also 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}_\infty = \sigma \bigg( \bigcup_{0\leq t < \infty} \mathcal{F}_t \bigg) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+).
\end{align}
Now, pick a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}_+$ that is not a Borel set. Then take $A_t = \{t\}$ if $t \in A$ and take $A_t = \emptyset$ otherwise.

Even if $A = \cup_{t\in \mathbb{R}_+} A_t$ and each $A_t \in \mathcal{F}_t$, for me it is not clear why $A$ fails to be a member of $\mathcal{F}_\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question. The explanation is simple.

We have, for all $t\in \mathbb{R}_+$, $A_t \in \mathcal{F}_t$ and so  $A_t \in \sigma \bigg( \bigcup_{0\leq t < \infty} \mathcal{F}_t \bigg)$. So, any COUNTABLE union os those $A_t$ will be in $\sigma \bigg( \bigcup_{0\leq t < \infty} \mathcal{F}_t \bigg)$.

We have $A = \cup_{t\in \mathbb{R}_+} A_t$.

If $A$ is countable then $\cup_{t\in \mathbb{R}_+} A_t$ reduces to a countable union and we have $A\in \sigma \bigg( \bigcup_{0\leq t < \infty} \mathcal{F}_t \bigg)$.

However, if $A$ is uncountable then  $\cup_{t\in \mathbb{R}_+} A_t$ does not reduce to a countable union and so it may possibly not be in $\sigma \bigg( \bigcup_{0\leq t < \infty} \mathcal{F}_t \bigg)$.